# Counting Sort Error Message

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to implement a counting sort algorithm using C, but I keep on getting segmentation faults during testing of a million integers. Any help please? My code is as below ("type.h" gives the typedef "unit" for unsigned int data type):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "csort.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "type.h"

unsigned int*
countingSort(unsigned int *A, int n) {
        uint i, j, l = 0, k = 0;
        uint *C;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (A[i] > k)
                    k = A[i];
        C = (uint*)malloc((sizeof(uint))*(k+1));
        for (i = 0; i <= k; i++)
            C[i] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            C[A[i]]++;
        for (i = 1; i < k; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < C[i]; j++)
                    A[l++] = i;
        free(C);
        return A;
}
```

The input I am dealing with is large numbers and so k is large. n is the number of integers in the input array (one million).

Answer (score 0):

What is the maximum of all the integers? If it is very large (say `2*10^9`) then you might run into problem of allocating `2*10^9 * sizeof(int)` which might caught segmentation fault.

Comment: The maximum integer is very large, but I'm using the data type of an unsigned integer. What should I do to rectify this then?

Comment: No, the problem is not with the data type. The problem is you are allocating a very large chunk of memory. Couting sort does not work in this example because **you do not know the range of integers beforehand**. For counting sort to work, the necessary condition is that the range of items is `known and small` (say 1 million). In the worst case of your algorithm, it requires `2*10^9 * 4 bytes = 7.4 GB` => segmentation fault. I would advise against using counting sort in this problem, rather using more traditional sorts (quicksort, mergesort).

Comment: Then you still use `3.7GB` which is still very large. If it is say 10000 your code will definitely work. Refers to [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).

Comment: What is acceptable for counting sort is usually something under 1 million.

Comment: But it should still work. My friend implemented a counting sort algorithm for 1 million integers of high numbers but it worked for him.